# SQL Server view not getting any results

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new to SQL Server and I'm trying to create a view that has all my customer information.

The `Customer` is my main table that I want to bring in all of the other tables on if the customer exists.

I tried using SQL Server Management Studio but it gave me zero results.

This is what my tables look like that I have selected:

[image]

I want the branch out of `Corporation` and the `AccountNumber` out of `Account` and all of the rest of the columns in the other tables.

This is what the management studio gave me:

```
SELECT     
   Customer.Customer.*, Customer.Miscellaneous2.*, Common.Address.*, 
   Company.CorporationStructure.Branch AS Expr1, Customer.Delivery.*, 
   Customer.Miscellaneous.*, Customer.Account.AccountNumber AS Expr2 
FROM         
   Customer.Account 
INNER JOIN
   Common.Address ON Customer.Account.AccountId = Common.Address.ForeignId 
INNER JOIN
   Company.CorporationStructure ON Customer.Account.CorporationStructureId = Company.CorporationStructure.CorporationStructureId 
                       AND Customer.Account.CorporationStructureId = Company.CorporationStructure.CorporationStructureId 
 INNER JOIN
    Customer.Customer ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Customer.Branch 
 INNER JOIN
    Customer.Delivery ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Delivery.Branch 
 INNER JOIN
    Customer.Miscellaneous ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Miscellaneous.Branch 
 INNER JOIN
    Customer.Miscellaneous2 ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Miscellaneous2.Branch
```

It returns zero results.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

=== UPDATE ===

I updated the query as suggested:

```
SELECT     Customer.Customer.IsActive, Customer.Customer.CompanyCode, Customer.Customer.Branch, Customer.Customer.Account, Customer.Customer.TypeCompanyTank, 
                      Customer.Customer.SalesManCode, Customer.Customer.Name, Customer.Customer.Street, Customer.Customer.City, Customer.Customer.State, 
                      Customer.Customer.ZipCode, Customer.Customer.ZipCodeExtension, Customer.Customer.AreaCode, Customer.Customer.PhoneNumber, Customer.Customer.TaxCode, 
                      Customer.Customer.CreditCode, Customer.Customer.Type1, Customer.Customer.FinanceChargeCode, Customer.Customer.StatementInvoiceCode, 
                      Customer.Customer.OpenItemBalanceForward, Customer.Customer.BillingTransaction, Customer.Customer.BudgetChange, Customer.Customer.DelinquentLetter, 
                      Customer.Customer.PriceClassA, Customer.Customer.PriceClassB, Customer.Customer.PriceClassC, Customer.Customer.PriceClassR, 
                      Customer.Customer.InvoiceTerms, Customer.Customer.DefaultProductCode, Customer.Customer.DefaultUnitOfIssue, Customer.Customer.Type2, 
                      Customer.Customer.BillingCycle, Customer.Customer.CurrentBalance, Customer.Customer.Over30, Customer.Customer.Over60, Customer.Customer.Over90, 
                      Customer.Customer.Over120, Customer.Customer.PreviousStatmentBalance, Customer.Customer.DepositAmount, Customer.Customer.LastPaymenRecievedDate, 
                      Customer.Customer.LastPaymentRecievedAmount, Customer.Customer.BudgetRate, Customer.Customer.NonBudgetBalance, Customer.Customer.BudgetBalance, 
                      Customer.Customer.UnpaidFinanceCharges, Customer.Customer.StartDate, Customer.Customer.CreditRecord, Customer.Customer.CreditLimit, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.IsActive AS Expr3, Customer.Miscellaneous2.CompanyCode AS Expr4, Customer.Miscellaneous2.Branch AS Expr5, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.Account AS Expr6, Customer.Miscellaneous2.BillingCycleCode, Customer.Miscellaneous2.LatitudeDegree, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.LatitudeDecimal, Customer.Miscellaneous2.North, Customer.Miscellaneous2.LongitudeDegree, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.LongitudeDecimal, Customer.Miscellaneous2.West, Customer.Miscellaneous2.GEOResultCode, Customer.Miscellaneous2.DeliveryState, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.DeliveryZipCode, Customer.Miscellaneous2.DeliveryZipCodeExtension, Customer.Miscellaneous2.RouteBook, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.DriverRouteSequence, Customer.Miscellaneous2.StandingPurchaseOrderNumber, Customer.Miscellaneous2.PhoneType2, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.AreaCode2, Customer.Miscellaneous2.PhoneNumber2, Customer.Miscellaneous2.PhoneType3, Customer.Miscellaneous2.PhoneNumber3, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.EmailAddress, Customer.Miscellaneous2.ElectronicLetterOption, Customer.Miscellaneous2.ElectronicPostcardOption, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.ElectronicStatementOption, Customer.Miscellaneous2.ElectronicInvoiceOption, Customer.Miscellaneous2.LossReason, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.LossYear, Customer.Miscellaneous2.LossMonth, Customer.Miscellaneous2.GainReason, Customer.Miscellaneous2.GainYear, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2.GainMonth, Customer.Miscellaneous2.LastSalesActivityDate, Customer.Miscellaneous2.ElectricTankMonitorNumber, 
                      Common.Address.AddressId, Common.Address.ForeignId, Common.Address.AddressType, Common.Address.Street AS Expr7, Common.Address.City AS Expr8, 
                      Common.Address.State AS Expr9, Common.Address.ZipCode AS Expr10, Common.Address.ZipCodeExtension AS Expr11, Common.Address.FromFlatFile, 
                      Common.Address.IsUpdated, Common.Address.IsAdded, Common.Address.ClearUpdateAndAdded, Common.Address.CorporationId, 
                      Company.CorporationStructure.Branch AS Expr1, Customer.Delivery.CompanyCode AS Expr12, Customer.Delivery.Branch AS Expr13, 
                      Customer.Delivery.Account AS Expr14, Customer.Delivery.IsActive AS Expr15, Customer.Delivery.DegreeDayBase, Customer.Delivery.DeliveryCode, 
                      Customer.Delivery.UseCode, Customer.Delivery.PostcardInOutFlag, Customer.Delivery.Driver, Customer.Delivery.Route, Customer.Delivery.RouteSequence, 
                      Customer.Delivery.PreviousPercent, Customer.Delivery.PercentFull, Customer.Delivery.TankSerialNumber, Customer.Delivery.TankType, Customer.Delivery.TankUnit,
                       Customer.Delivery.TicketInOutFlag, Customer.Delivery.LockUseOrRateCode, Customer.Delivery.QuantityLastDelivered, Customer.Delivery.TankSize, 
                      Customer.Delivery.NumberOfTanks, Customer.Delivery.NumberOfCompanyTanks, Customer.Delivery.GallonsPerDegreeDay, Customer.Delivery.GallonsPerDay, 
                      Customer.Delivery.HeatingConfidence, Customer.Delivery.DailyConfidence, Customer.Delivery.LastDeliveryDate, Customer.Delivery.LastDeliveryDegreeDay, 
                      Customer.Delivery.OptimumDeliveryDateOrDegreeDay, Customer.Delivery.RunOutDeliveryDateOrDegreeDay, Customer.Delivery.GasCheck, 
                      Customer.Delivery.YearToDateDeliveries, Customer.Delivery.YearToDateGasDelivered, Customer.Delivery.TotalGasUsedLastYear, Customer.Delivery.AXGasUsed1, 
                      Customer.Delivery.AXGasUsed2, Customer.Delivery.AXGasUsed3, Customer.Delivery.AXGasUsed4, Customer.Delivery.AXGasUsed5, 
                      Customer.Delivery.AXDailyUsed1, Customer.Delivery.AXDailyUsed2, Customer.Delivery.AXDailyUsed3, Customer.Delivery.AXDailyUsed4, 
                      Customer.Delivery.AXDailyUsed5, Customer.Delivery.AXDays1, Customer.Delivery.AXDays2, Customer.Delivery.AXDays3, Customer.Delivery.AXDays4, 
                      Customer.Delivery.AXDays5, Customer.Miscellaneous.IsActive AS Expr16, Customer.Miscellaneous.CompanyCode AS Expr17, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous.Branch AS Expr18, Customer.Miscellaneous.Account AS Expr19, Customer.Miscellaneous.CareOf, Customer.Miscellaneous.DeliveryStreet, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous.DeliveryCity, Customer.Miscellaneous.PurchaseOrderNumber, Customer.Miscellaneous.MasterBillingBranch, 
                      Customer.Miscellaneous.MasterBillingAccount, Customer.Account.AccountNumber AS Expr2
FROM         Customer.Account LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Common.Address ON Customer.Account.AccountId = Common.Address.ForeignId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Company.CorporationStructure ON Customer.Account.CorporationStructureId = Company.CorporationStructure.CorporationStructureId AND 
                      Customer.Account.CorporationStructureId = Company.CorporationStructure.CorporationStructureId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Customer.Customer ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Customer.Branch LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Customer.Delivery ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Delivery.Branch LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Customer.Miscellaneous ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Miscellaneous.Branch LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Customer.Miscellaneous2 ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Miscellaneous2.Branch
```

Now I'm getting a result but now I'm getting the same customer over and over again:

[image]

Comment: To test this, go one join at a time to see where the data is falling out.

Comment: There are a lot of INNER JOINs in that statement, probably need to use LEFT JOINs for at least some of the tables

Comment: I have updated the query as you suggested.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized. Build your query up one join at a time and see where it appears to go wrong. Then if you can't figure out why ask a specific question about that. Doubt many people feel like trying to debug your 7 table join with no knowledge of the data or any FK constraints you may have.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't change ALL of the inner joins to be left outer joins.  Only change the join to an outer if you don't want the results reduced if there's no record in the 2nd table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably because of the double join to company corporate structure.  The problem lines are:

```
INNER JOIN
    Customer.Customer ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Customer.Branch 
 INNER JOIN
    Customer.Delivery ON Company.CorporationStructure.Branch = Customer.Delivery.Branch
```

You need to have CorporateStructure appear twice in the `from` clause, once for the customer and once for the delivery.

Comment: You are right, I have to change the query to have it link off the CorporationStructure but I need to start with the account. I will make the change.